# Es posible solapar contenido sobre otro sin modificar la posición de los demás?

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando crear unas listas que no se muestren completas. Solo quiero que se muestre la que esta como "activa" y asemeja el encabezado. Después, con `css` quiero que al pasar el ratón se muestre el contenido. Este es el avance:

```css
.list-contenedor {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.list-maquina {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  transition: width 200ms;
}

.list-maquina:hover {
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.list-maquina .list-orden {
  display: none;
  transition: display 500ms;
}

.list-maquina:hover .list-orden {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-auto ">
    <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
      <li class="list-group-item active d-flex justify-content-between">
        Texto
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden">Item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden disabled">
        No hay ordenes asignadas
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="col-auto ">
    <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
      <li class="list-group-item active d-flex justify-content-between">
        Texto
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden">Item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden disabled">
        No hay ordenes asignadas
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto ">
    <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
      <li class="list-group-item active d-flex justify-content-between">
        Texto
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden">Item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-orden disabled">
        No hay ordenes asignadas
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero prevenir es que todo se re acomode. No me causaría problema el echo de que lo demás se movieran pero cuando el elemento se encuentra al costado derecho este se mueve hacia abajo, quitando del foco toda la caja. Como resolver este problema?

Comment: ¿Es forzoso que tenga ese width de 400px al hacer hover?

Comment: No. Se aceptan propuestas que cumplan con el objetivo de que lo demás no se mueva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre resolverlo modificando un poco la estructura

```css
.list-contenedor {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px; 
  height: 50px;
  position: unset;
  
}

.list-maquina{
 position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.list-orden-grupo{
 position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 100ms;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover {
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.list-orden-grupo .list-orden  {
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .list-orden {
  position: static;
  visibility:visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 200ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

 <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2">

  <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">


   <span class="list-orden-grupo">

        <li class="list-group-item active d-flex shadow justify-content-between">
          Texto
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          No hay ordenes asignadas
        </li>

      </span>


  </ul>
 </div>
  
  <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2">

  <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">


   <span class="list-orden-grupo">

        <li class="list-group-item active d-flex shadow justify-content-between">
          Texto
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          No hay ordenes asignadas
        </li>

      </span>


  </ul>
 </div>
  
  <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2">

  <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">


   <span class="list-orden-grupo">

        <li class="list-group-item active d-flex shadow justify-content-between">
          Texto
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          No hay ordenes asignadas
        </li>

      </span>


  </ul>
 </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2">

  <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">


   <span class="list-orden-grupo">

        <li class="list-group-item active d-flex shadow justify-content-between">
          Texto
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          No hay ordenes asignadas
        </li>

      </span>


  </ul>
 </div>
  <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2">

  <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">


   <span class="list-orden-grupo">

        <li class="list-group-item active d-flex shadow justify-content-between">
          Texto
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
         <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          dsdf
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
          No hay ordenes asignadas
        </li>

      </span>


  </ul>
 </div>
  
</div>
```